# How to modify Ring's background color via property nodes?

Tags: labview

Assigning background color at edit time works for all ring controls except "System ring":
[image]

I am trying to modify the background color of a Ring control using the RingText.BGColor property node, but it doesn't work. It *does work* for a Numeric control though:

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: Did you look up the resulting error code? Code 1131 - this property can not be used on this type of control.

Comment: @shmicah there are no error codes whatsoever from what I see

Comment: Have you disabled automatic error handling on the VI? If you enable it, or put an error output on the RingNum property node, you will see the error. Unfortunately, colors can't be set on a Ring despite it being "available" in the property selector.

Comment: @shmicah automatic error handling is enabled and yeah I wired error indicators: no errors displayed.

Comment: I find that hard to believe - what LV version are you? I'm in 2015. Maybe I'm missing something but I doubt it. Will another data type work for you?

Comment: @shmicah version 2013. Any numbered text control will do

Comment: You can use an Enum or a TextRing and change BG color, but its just the interior border. If the color will be static, then you can make it a TypeDef and use the color tool to color it however you want. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @shmicah, menu rings do not support dynamically setting of bgcolor. However, this can be "solved" by first creating a text ring and then replacing it (right click -> replace) with a menu ring. Interestingly, this method works for the "modern" and "silver" menu rings but not for the classic.

After replacing the text ring with a menu ring, the original code works as-is.

(LabVIEW 2013)