# How to reorder controls in cluster without breaking existing references?

Tags: labview

I would like to reorder controls in a cluster (typedef) to set a tab order that makes sense. When I do it [as instructed](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/lvhowto/changingtheorderoffpanelob/), the already existing references to controls within the cluster get mixed up.

Here is a screenshot of the control typedef and the block diagram before and after reordering the controls:
[image]

... after saving the changes in the control, LabVIEW automatically changed the references, probably in an attempt to maintain the same order (and not the same label).

Is there a way to maintain the integrity of my references (I have a lot) after changing the tab order?

Comment: Is the cluster a typedef?

Comment: @Dave_St yes it is.

Comment: As long as the names of the controls within the cluster aren't changing, it shouldn't be a problem. Is the typedef used everywhere the cluster is referenced? Are you using unbundle/bundle by name or just the simple versions?

Comment: @Dave_St I'm not using unbundle by name, but only direct references to the controls within the cluster typedef. I do this because I need access to the refnum.

Comment: I have never tried it that way. I've only ever used generic control refs in the typedef and then bundled the specific control ref on init, using either a shift register or an action engine to hold the ref until the program quits. Without code to see, I'm not sure what else to tell you.

Comment: @Dave_St screenshot added.

Comment: You've apparently reordered the controls in the cluster but not reordered the indicators connected to them (numeric value to string indicator, boolean value to numeric indicator, etc). Also this seems like example code you've created to illustrate your problem instead of the actual code. I can see why you'd do that but I don't think it shows enough code to properly convey your issue. What controls are those references attached to? Can you attach a vi that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: @Dave_St what's the point of using references if I need to reorder the controls? This example conveys the issue accurately: absolutely nothing changed in my app other than the tab order. Now imagine I have 200 of such controls... Note that LabVIEW changed the references automatically after I saved the changes in the tab order - I didn't do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've definitely found some non user-friendly behavior here. But I would also argue your sample code here defeats the purpose of a cluster by referencing each element individually within the cluster.

If you have a TypeDef Cluster, create a reference to the entire cluster, not the individual elements within. Then, you can use a Value Property Node on the entire cluster and unbundle the elements you want.

If your reference breaks, save the VI and it will fix it (shouldn't break though).

Here is my TypeDef Cluster before:
[image]

Then I reordered (note FP control order), but Cluster reference is not broken and unbundle function still gives correct values:
[image]

Comment: I didn't realize this was possible! Thanks! Is there also a way to get the refnum of each control by name?

Comment: Same property node, but the "Controls[]" option near the bottom. It will give an array of references to the cluster elements in order.

Comment: Yeah but I cannot extract the refnum by name this way, it's just a 1D array

Comment: If "by name" you mean the indicators label, you can iterate through the array of references and use a Property Node to get the Label.Text (front panel label), then you know which ref is for which control. However, this is pretty sloppy. If you are heavily reliant on breaking out references to access variables you may need to rethink your architecture.

Comment: I need the refnums to [access bgcolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48793777)...

Comment: Well the refnums are right there in the array, and you can operate on each individually to identify which control they belong to and perform actions on them. I think you would be well served making an [action engine](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Community-Nugget-4-08-2007-Action-Engines/td-p/503801) to update BG colors. It would be a one stop shop to get cluster references, read/write BG color, etc. How you decide which control gets what color is up to you, but in an AE you'd do it once and be done basically.